# Not able to install Search while upgrading to Azure Devops 2019 Server update 1.1

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

I am upgrading from Azure Devops 2019 server to Azure Devops 2019 Update 1.1 (on-premises). Earlier setup has search configured and prior to the upgrade I could see the service "elasticsearch-service-x64" running. After the upgrade to Update 1.1 while configuring installed features the upgrade wizard error-ed out. I am also not seeing any service running with title: "elasticsearch-service-x64"

This is the log file:

```
+-+-+-+-+-| Running InstallElasticsearch: Installing Elasticsearch service ... |+-+-+-+-+-

+-+-+-+-+-| Installing Elasticsearch service ... |+-+-+-+-+-
Starting Node: CINSTALLESSERVICE
NodePath : Container/Conditional/Container/Progress/Conditional/CINSTALLESSERVICE
Adding JAVA_HOME to the environment of child process, value: C:\Program Files (x86)\jdk1.8.0_121
Process starting: fileName=cmd.exe arguments=elasticsearch-service.bat install
Process finished: fileName=cmd.exe arguments=elasticsearch-service.bat install exitCode=255 in 470 ms
Installing service      :  "elasticsearch-service-x64"
Using JAVA_HOME (64-bit):  "C:\Program Files (x86)\jdk1.8.0_121"
\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe" -cp "!ES_CLASSPATH!" "org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser" "!ES_JVM_OPTIONS!" || echo jvm_options_parser_failed"`) was unexpected at this time.
Waiting for Elasticsearch operation to complete...
Exception Message: Elasticsearch operation was timedout. (type ElasticsearchOperationTimedoutException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.Search.ElasticsearchInstaller.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Install>b__0()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.Search.ElasticsearchInstaller.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<InvokeServiceBatCommand>b__0()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.RetryManager.Invoke(Action action)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.Search.ElasticsearchInstaller.Install(String esHome, IActivityLog logger, String serviceAccountName, String serviceAccountPassword)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ConfigureInstallSearchESService.Run(ActivityContext context)
Node returned: Error
VS403185: An unknown error has occurred during Search configuration. Retry the operation and if problem persists, please contact Microsoft Customer Support(https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=808053) for help.
Completed InstallElasticsearch: Error
```

Any suggestion as to what could I be missing?